# Dual boot Windows 10 & Ubuntu 20.04 Grub issues

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot. My boot option was set to windows as first choice and Ubuntu as 2nd . Recently I was using Ubuntu (after many months) and when I restarted the system, the grub menu was not showing up. It was "System bootloader not found. Initializing default" message and system keep restarting. so now I have no way to login into my windows as well. I couldn't access BIOS as well (unless I disconnect the power cord and connect after few hours. At that time it shows clock error and allows me to access BIOS)

I used Live Ubuntu USB to trouble shoot the issue

(following this link: https://ictsolved.github.io/recover-efi-grub-in-linux/)

and tried reinstalling grub but it is failing with Input/Output error.

I checked /efi/EFI folder (after mounting the /dev/sda2 where EFI partition is installed) and found the below .

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt/boot/efi/EFI$ ls -lrt
ls: cannot access 'ubuntu': Input/output error
total 12392
d????????? ? ?    ?           ?            ? ubuntu
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     1024 Jul 23  2020 Boot
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12687184 Jul 24  2021 WindowsBoot.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     1024 Jul 26  2021 Microsoft
```

fdisk command returns the below. so i think my windows is still good. it's just I am not able to access it .

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1085439   1083392  529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2    1085440   1288191    202752   99M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1288192   1320959     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1320960 840071190 838750231  400G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  840073216 937719807  97646592 46.6G Linux filesystem
```

Appreciate any help in fixing this / grub issues to get both my Windows and Ubuntu back !!

Comment: You can use boot-repair from a live USB to fix GRUB. But if Windows doesn't boot when you choose Windows from your motherboard BIOS during startup, then you need to consult with Windows documentation or support. Nothing in Ubuntu will affect your Windows partition or boot manager unless you manually change or alter those files or partitions.

Comment: Thanks! .   Boot repair also did not work. Getting a error popup when tried to do the boot-repair.  With respect to BIOS, as I  mentioned, hitting F1 , F12 is doing nothing to access BIOS. Only way for me to access BIOS is to disconnect the power cord and try after few hours and because of CMOS Clock sync , I am able to access the BIOS.  Through that option, I will check the BIOS and report back here. Thanks again !

Comment: Be sure to keep your question up-to-date by editing it. You should add the boot repair summary as well as the details and results of any attempts you've made. Be thorough and exact, otherwise the information you provide may not be useful if we have to guess what you mean.

Comment: Is this an older system? Clock errors are often related to old coin battery on motherboard that remembers settings like clock? Full shutdown is a "cold" boot. Do you have in UEFI setting a fast boot setting, that is different than Windows fast start up and often fast boot is so fast from a warm reboot, you do not have time to press they key to get back into UEFI, unless you cold boot. Check UEFI settings.